# .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 migration - Microsoft Identity Web Platform stopped working

Tags: azure-active-directory, .net-5, microsoft-identity-platform

With NET 5 officially released, this evening I've migrated from Net Core 3.1 to NET 5, all seemed to go smoothly until I tried to run the app and now find a couple of squiggly lines under two items in the startup.cs that are associated with Microsoft Identity Web platform. This is obviously an instant fail! I wont be able to fire up the app or login to Azure AD until I have this fixed.

After modifying the csproj file to NET5, I then went to nuget manager and updated all the packages.

I've absolutely no idea where to start on this issue :(

Screenshot of the startup.cs file with the squiggles:

[image: startup.cs file]

csproj file:

[image]

Nuget Manager with updated packages:

[image]

I notice that the package references at the top of the startup.cs file for MS Identity Web are now greyed out since the migration:

[image]

Code from the startup.cs file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public TokenValidatedContext Context { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Added to original .net core template.
        // ASP.NET Core apps access the HttpContext through the IHttpContextAccessor interface and 
        // its default implementation HttpContextAccessor. It's only necessary to use IHttpContextAccessor 
        // when you need access to the HttpContext inside a service.
        // Example usage - we're using this to retrieve the details of the currrently logged in user in page model actions.
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        // DO NOT DELETE (for now...)
        // This 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI' library was originally used for Azure Ad authentication 
        // before we implemented the newer Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet packages. 
        // Note after implememting the newer library for authetication, we had to modify the _LoginPartial.cshtml file.
        //services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        //    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        ///////////////////////////////////

        // Add services required for using options.
        // e.g used for calling Graph Api from WebOptions class, from config file.
        services.AddOptions();

        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        services.AddSignIn(Configuration);

        // Token acquisition service based on MSAL.NET
        // and chosen token cache implementation
        services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { GraphScopes.UserRead })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        // Add the MS Graph SDK Client as a service for Dependancy Injection.
        services.AddGraphService(Configuration);

        // Create a new instance of the class that stores the methods called
        // by OpenIdConnectEvents(); i.e. when a user logs in or out the app.
        // See section below :- 'services.Configure'
        OpenIdEvents openIdEvents = new OpenIdEvents();

        // The following lines code instruct the asp.net core middleware to use the data in the "roles" claim in the Authorize attribute and User.IsInrole()
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2 for more info.
        
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are available.
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            // Advanced config - capturing user events. See OpenIdEvents class.
            options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated += openIdEvents.OnTokenValidatedFunc;
            // This is event is fired when the user is redirected to the MS Signout Page (before they've physically signed out)
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut += openIdEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOutFunc;
            // DO NOT DELETE - May use in the future.
            // OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect doesn't produce any user claims to read from for the user after they have signed out.
            options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += openIdEvents.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirectFunc;
        });

        // Adding authorization policies that enforce authorization using Azure AD roles. Polices defined in seperate classes.
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // This line may not work for razor at all, havent tried it but what was used in MVC from the MS Project example. Dont delete just yet...
            //options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToUserReaderRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireRole(AppRole.UserReaders));

            // NOTE BELOW - I had to change the syntax from RequireRole to RequireClaim
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToEditRolesRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AppRole.EditRoles));
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToViewLogsRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AppRole.ViewLogs));
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToViewUsersRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AppRole.ViewUsers));
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToCreateUsersRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AppRole.CreateUsers));
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToEditUsersRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AppRole.EditUsers));
            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToDeleteUsersRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, AppRole.DeleteUsers));
        });

        services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        // Add the HttpClient factory into our dependancy injection system.
        // That way we can access it at any point.
        // Used for consuming REST Api throughout the Webb App.
        services.AddHttpClient();
        // Adds the service for creating the Jwt Token used for calling microservices.
        // Note we are using our independant bearer token issuer service here, NOT Azure AD
        services.AddScoped<JwtService>();
        // Add service for HttpContext Current User Repository.
        // Used fir fetching properties of the currently logged in user for logging.
        services.AddScoped<ICurrentUser, CurrentUser>();

        // The AddAntiforgery() method configures anti-forgery service to pick the anti-forgery 
        // token from request headers rather than request body. This is required because we will 
        // be issuing Ajax requests to the razor page and there won't be any full page post-backs.
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "MY-XSRF-TOKEN");
    }
```

I just don't know how to troubleshoot this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it working. The first issue I got the answer from another post:

The services.AddSignIn() is available in the nuget package of Microsoft.Identity.Web up to version 0.1.5 Preview version, the above versions don't contain the services.AddSignIn()

In my case I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Web ver 1.3.0

I replaced the code shown directly below with the code section at the bottom:

Old Code:

```
    // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
    services.AddSignIn(Configuration);

    // Token acquisition service based on MSAL.NET
    // and chosen token cache implementation
    services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { GraphScopes.UserRead })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Replaced the above with the following code:

```
   // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
   //services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
   services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
   // Token acquisition service based on MSAL.NET and chosen token cache implementation
       .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { GraphScopes.UserRead })
       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I've run some quick checks to ensure that I'm able to perform changes to a user profile which is using the MS Graph so I'm comfortable enough this solved my issue.